# Docker equivalent Remote API command for -p 80:80?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start docker container with docker's Remote API. I could able to start the container but unable to expose and map the container's port to host port.

I need Remote API JSON for following ssh command

```
docker run -i -t --expose 80 -p 80:80 my_image_nodejs nodejs /var/www/server.js
```

Right now i'm using below JSON.

```
{
    "Image": "f96f6e304cfcd630ee51af87baf30dfd42cf1f361da873a2f62ce6654d7a4c6b",
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "VolumesFrom": "",
    "Cmd": [
        "nodejs",
        "/var/www/server.js",
        "-D"
    ],
    "PortBindings": {
        "80/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "80"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "80/tcp": {}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me :

**Container create** :

ExposedPorts: {"80/tcp": {}, "22/tcp" : {}}

**Container start** :

PortBindings: {"80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "80" }],"22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "22" }]
}

If you know how to set up Env, I've just sent my question :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your request should be below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":true,"AttachStderr":true,
    "ExposedPorts": { "80/tcp": {}},
    "Cmd": [
        "nodejs","/var/www/server.js","-D"
    ],
    "HostConfig":{
        "PortBindings": { "80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "80" }] }
    },
    "Image":"my_image_nodejs",
    "Tag":"latest"
}' $DOCKER_DAEMON/containers/create
```

where ***$DOCKER_DAEMON*** is the host listening remote requests.
The ***PortBindings*** and ***ExposedPorts*** are in different sections. You may want to refer more detail on Docker remote API [v1.22](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#create-a-container).

Hope this helps.